# How to select community wiki questions?

Tags: support, data-explorer, community-wiki

I want to write a query which selects the highest scored community-wiki questions (like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)) but I don't have an idea how to do it. This is what I have so far:

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1166501/find-top-wiki-questions

1. How to do it?
2. It is also possible to select question which are NOT community-wiki? If yes: how to do it?

UPDATE - info:

Community-wiki posts are slightly different than community-wiki-locked posts - how to deal with it [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/340239/how-to-select-community-wiki-locked-questions)

Comment: `AND CommunityOwnedDate is not null`

Comment: @rene if today you write your comment as answer I will accept it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You seem to have adjusted your query already (perhaps after @rene's comment which I failed to spot at first); it is working fine.

There's no `IsCommunityWiki` boolean/bit column in the `Posts` table; instead, you have to check the `CommunityOwnedDate` which is `NULL` if and only if it's *not* a community wiki post. So

```
AND p.CommunityOwnedDate is not null
```

selects community wiki posts only, and

```
AND p.CommunityOwnedDate is null
```

would only select posts which are *not* community wiki.

Comment: This question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-do-i-redirect-to-another-webpage is strage - it is written on its top "community wiki" however we see its author - and for this question `CommunityOwnedDate=null`  - do you know how to 'select' this kind of questions? Or may be I should write separate question about this?

Comment: That's not a community wiki question, it's a question with a 'Community Wiki' lock. That's slightly different; it disables edits (on the question) completely, instead of lowering the edit barrier. How to select those should be a separate question.