# How to select 'community wiki locked' questions?

Tags: support, data-explorer, locked-questions

I want to write a query which selects the highest scored community-wiki-lock questions (like this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-do-i-redirect-to-another-webpage)). This is not typical comunity-wiki question like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php) - but comunity-wiki-lock (e.g. we see there the original question author without 'wiki' info). For community-wiki it is enough to use `CommunityOwnedDate is not null` in query, but it not working for wiki-locked questions. This is what I have so far:

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1166505/find-top-community-wiki-locked-questions

1. How to do it?
2. How to select non community-wiki-lock questions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those are post notices with a specific type ID, namely 23. You can find them by joining to the `PostNotices` table:

```
INNER JOIN PostNotices AS pn
   ON p.Id = pn.PostId
  AND pn.PostNoticeTypeId = 23
  AND pn.DeletionDate IS NULL -- non-deleted notices only
```

[This query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1166507) helps to find them; there are currently only 48 of those on Stack Overflow.

[image]

To *exclude* these kind of questions, you could use an outer join:

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN PostNotices AS pn
   ON p.Id = pn.PostId
  AND pn.PostNoticeTypeId = 23
  AND pn.DeletionDate IS NULL
```

and add `AND pn.Id IS NULL` to your `WHERE` clause.

You might wonder where that magic number 23 is coming from. There's a small table `PostNoticeTypes`, if you scroll down in the sidebar widget with the database schema, you'll notice it has a little 'information' icon (left). When you click on it, you see the contents of the table (right). Scroll down until you reach the post notice type you're looking for:

[image]
[image]