# How can I find questions marked as "community effort"?

Tags: support, search, community-wiki

Recently a new banner has appeared on some wiki questions where you can only edit existing answers rather than posting a new one:

> [image: community effort]

For instance: [What is serial voting and how does it affect me?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126829/339911)

Is there a way to search for such questions via search options? It seems that [`wiki:1 is:q answers:1 hasnotice:1`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=wiki%3A1%20is%3Aq%20answers%3A1%20hasnotice%3A1) is not enough. Maybe it's possible via a SEDE query?

Comment: SEDE should work, as it's a lock reason AFAIK and post nltices are included in SEDE. (PostNoticeTypes.Id=23)

Comment: Somehow I failed to remember this question that I answered: [How to select 'community wiki locked' questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/340239/295232)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's post notice type 23, so [this SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1228861) should work. It's interesting to see that post notices are kept in the SEDE database even for deleted questions (the ones not rendering in the results).

[image]

Comment: is there a reason why this cant be added like a tag which makes is it easier to find?