# Allow voting on Community Effort questions

Tags: feature-request, voting, community-wiki

There is a special type of questions marked as ["community effort"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/346703/339911). For unobvious reason there is not possible to vote (or edit) on the question, since question is locked. But on the same time voting and edits are allowed on the answer. I see no reason why the voting is forbidden for the question. Can we make such questions vote available?

In my point of view community effort questions are not ordinary locked posts when voting/editing is prohibited according [this old answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/36966/339911) from former SO employee.

In particular this limitation on voting prevents marking some questions as "community effort" by ruSO moderators: [Пометить вики-вопросы с предполагаемым единственным ответом нужным статусом](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/10392/176217)

Comment: @ShadowKeepsSocialDistance Not a duplicate, he proposes other change.

Comment: @Tinkeringbell Not a duplicate, he proposes other change.

Comment: @Qwertiy While the exact examples they give are different, the general gist of what they said is still applicable to this question. (The "wiki answer" lock reason didn't exist at the time the request was filed, which is why the question doesn't cite it, but it would also refer to it today.) Also, the answer there by me addresses this specific case.

Comment: @SonictheStay-HomeHedgehog, this proposal is much more simple to change, than the things from that question. And that question was forgotten 8 years ago.